# How to understand comma-separated value (CSV) format Dictionary on a website without downloading vb or spss to my mac?

Tags: macos, csv, spss

I converted a SPSS dataset to CSV and am wondering if there is a website for me to read the file without downloading visual basic to my mac.. It's really hard to find a free and credible software source and I would really appreciated it if someone can recommend something that he tried before!

Comment: Why would you need VB to read a CSV file? In any case recommendations for software are off-topic here.

Comment: Hi thanks! I am totally not a techy person and as I was browsing posts on stackoverflow, someone mentioned VB. I actually used a website to convert the CSV to a plain text file but am just wondering if there is a better way to display and read the data.

Comment: CSV is always plain text - it's just that the file extension .csv is usually registered for Excel. You could simply change the extension from .csv to .txt.